# Why does option tag in select is not working after migrating from Angularjs 1.3 to 1.8 version?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I have been working on AngularJs 1.3 and the below code is working fine in 1.3 version but after migrating the Angularjs version to 1.8.2, the below code is not working as expected.

```
     <select class="form-control"  ng-model="formElement.params.customProperties['' + tabProperty.id]" >
        <option style = "color : #2C2C2C" value="">Default</option>
        <option style = "color : #3D5DFF" value = "attention-neutral-1-500">Blue</option>
        <option style = "color : #A35C00" value = "attention-warning-500">Brown</option>
        <option style = "color : #707070" value = "attention-neutral-2-500">Gray</option>
        <option style = "color : #008060" value = "attention-positive-500">Green</option>
        <option style = "color : #9C41DD" value = "attention-system-500">Purple</option>
        <option style = "color : #DC0C22" value = "attention-negative-500">Red</option>
</select>
```

I have a button named as "close" after this dropdown and this dropdown is inside a popup.

AngularJS 1.3 --> After selecting any value in dropdown, then clicking on close button, there persist the selected value (i.e. after again opening the popup the previously selected value is selected in dropdown).

AngularJS 1.8 --> After selecting any value in dropdown, then clicking on close button, the **selected value is not persisted (i.e. after again opening the popup the previously selected value is not selected in dropdown).**

Note: There is no any change in controller side as well.

Can anyone please help me what I am missing here or there is any major changes in select-option in Angularjs 1.8 version?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use ng-model in this was? 
If you want to autofill or make your selection persisting your options values and ng-model's values should match otherwise it won't work. 
Why not to just do ng-model="formElement.params.data" and then use it make your desired object?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in console? Are you certain that your ng-model is valid for the lifetime of the controller and never changes its containing object? That ng-model expression looks rather brittle.

Comment: @MarkClark I do not see any error message in the console. I have not changed the ng-model after migrating from 1.3 to 1.8. I also tried to print ng-model on console and it is populating the correct value as per the dropdown selection.